# how to prove $f^p\in L([0,1])(q \in (0,p))$ when $f^q \in L([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis

I've known that when $p>q\geq1$,then $L^p \subset L^q$,but when $q\in (0,p)$,I don't know how to prove that. 
When $\int_{[0,1]}|f|^pdx<\infty$,q\in (0,p),how can we get  $\int_{[0,1]}|f|^qdx<\infty$ ?

Appreciate with help!

Comment: Hölders inequality will save you .

Comment: $$\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{q}dx\leq \left(\int_{[0,1]}1^{\frac{p}{p-q}}dx\right)^{\frac{p-q}{q}}\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{q\frac{p}{q}}dx\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}=\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}$$  correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply Jensen's inequality with $\phi(t):=t^{\frac pq}$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality I wonder how does it work?